Парсер на python не работает у других пользователей
Парсер магазина Steam интегрирован в телеграмм бот на aiogram 3. Лично у меня всё работает, но попросил приятеля зайти в бота и проверить, у него ничего не работает, подозреваю что это из-за user-agent в headers:
headers = {
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "YaBrowser";v="24.7", "Yowser";v="2.5"',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?supportedlang=russian&os=win&filter=popularwishlist&ndl=1',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 YaBrowser/24.7.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}

params = {
    'review_score_preference': '0',
    'l': 'russian',
    'pagev6': 'true',
}

response = requests.get('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?supportedlang=russian&os=win&filter=popularwishlist&ndl=1', params=params, headers=headers)

если это всё таки из-за user-agent, есть ли возможность сделать так чтобы кто угодно мог пользоваться ботом ? Не писал бы сюда если бы мог сам решить проблему загуглив, но уже второй день ломаю голову.
Сам бот полностью рабочий, парсер работает прекрасно, но только у меня

Где ошибки, логи? Как Вы думаете, можно ли опираться на догадки!?

Никаких ошибок нет, в логах появляются только апдейты бота, другие пользователи просто не могут пользоваться им

Добавляйте значимые фрагменты кода...
